# Сервер обрабатывая post запрос не может дать ответ. node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
<form name="registerForm">
    <label>Name</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="number" name="password" />

    <button id="send">send</button>
</form>
```

тут форма

```
        if (count === elements.length) {
            const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open('post', 'http://localhost:3000/registration');
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            req.send(JSON.stringify(data));

            window.location.href = '/products';
            // window.location.reload();
        }
```

здесь, то что выполняется когда нажимаю на кнопку (кстати на кнопку поставил preventDefault)

```
app.get('/registration', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'registration.html'));
}) 
app.post('/registration', jsonParser, (req, res) => { 
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(res);
});
```

почему когда я отправляю запрос на сервер, post запрос, обрабатываемый сервером не может дать ответ (res.send) или сделать редирект? может из-за того, что на кнопке стоит preventDefault? можно, пожалуйста, подробнее

Comment: window.location.href я поставил как замену редиректу, но хотелось бы понять почему именно сервер на пост запросе после получения данных не может дать ответ (responce.send, responce.redirect)

Comment: Замените скрины на код в виде текста. Так же поясните, что значит не может дать ответ?

Comment: @SwaD когда я пишу в обработке post запроса на стороне сервера res.send или res.redirect эти функции просто не выполняются, хотя данные получены и console.log(req.body) выполняется

Comment: Потому что редирект выполняется браузером а не вашим сервером, и соответственно скриптами у клиента а не сервера :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков то есть, когда есть скрипт обработки формы на стороне клиента, то только он может делать редирект?

Comment: т.е. все что может сервер - послать клиенту ответ с "предложением" пойти по другому адресу, это предложение например код ответа [3xx](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#3xx) (Moved ....),или js скрипт редиректа который браузер выполнит(или нет)....  а делать что то или нет - решать "браузеру"

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков спасибо!